# Does Xen Support VMs with multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualization, xen

In short, I would like to know if Xen VMs support multiple monitors.  I'm interested in setting up a linux box that will achieve the following:

- 1 VM that utilizes a triple-monitor display (Linux)
- 1 VM that utilizes a single-monitor display (Windows)

The Linux host will be powered with a Radeon 4870.  The Xen VMs should be able to utilize Xen VGA Passthrough (at least the Windows one needs this).  The VMs will be powered with a Radeon 7870.

The two VMs do NOT need to be running simultaneously.  I will only be using one or the other at any given time.

If the VMs cannot support triple-monitor displays, would it be possible to set this up in another manner?  The 4870 only support 2 displays.  The 7870 can do 3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the graphical passthrough works correctly, then you will be able to run as many monitors as the graphics cards supports.  The graphical passthrough puts the entire graphics device in the domU, thus you'll be able to exercise all of the features of the card.  We currently use graphics passthrough on the Intel on-board graphics adapters, and use 2 or 3 displays, depending on the Intel model.